# When running javascript loop with internal call to code behind, the code behind runs only the first time

Tags: javascript, code-behind

When running Javascript loop,calling code behind with data, only the first line is showing. I need to get every time another value without reloading the page.

Here is the sample:

```
for (var counter = 0; counter < 50; counter++) {
  val = <%=  GetLon("500") %>;
  alert (val);
}
```

It calls only one time!!

Comment: How do you expect us to help if you don't post your code?

Comment: [Your code works 50 times](https://jsfiddle.net/L4cbf6zn/)

Comment: No! the code works 50 times but it calls the GetLon only1 time

Comment: Is `GetLon` asynchronous?

Comment: A simple function in code behind c#

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found this [response](https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/918294-javascript-loop-calling-code-behind):

> You can use an XMLHTTPRequest to call a server side code page. Once
>   the server has processed the code, it will call back to the client
>   with the processed page. You then use the call back function to pull
>   whatever data you need out of the result. The whole process is called
>   AJAX.

```
function ajaxExample() {
    var xmlhttp;
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.asp?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I didn't tested it yet, but looks to be the correct answer!